# SQLAlchemy connection pool - logger.error when pool is full?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

In SQLAlchemy's pool, is there a way to get a logger.error call, or to invoke some sort of callback, when a connection is attempted to be made but the pool(+overflow) is already using all of its allocated connections?

This is in a web server context - a logger.error would get reported to our Sentry instance, and so we could take action. Note - wanting the request to continue to wait for a connection until its configured timeout.

Having a nose around https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html, nothing leaps out at me. This is in Django, via https://github.com/altairbow/django-db-connection-pool, and nothing leaps out at me there in its docs or in its source.